# How to make pagination with observable

Tags: angular, spring-boot, pagination, observable, ngx-bootstrap

I have car-list.component.ts with:

```
**export class CarListComponent implements OnInit {

public cars$!: Observable<CarInterface[]>;

constructor(
private carService: CarService
#   ) {
#   }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.cars$ = this.carService.getAllCars();
#   }

# }**
```

car.service.ts

```
**export class CarService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  public getAllCars(): Observable<CarInterface[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CarInterface[]>('http://localhost:8080/car/cars');
  }

}**
```

and car.list.html

```
<body>
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="section-content section-content-p30">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div *ngFor="let car of cars$ | async" class="col-md-3">

          <div class="product-box">

            <img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,' + car.image }}" alt="">
            <h3>{{ car.name }}</h3>

            <div class="price">{{ car.price | currency:'USD' }}</div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add to cart</button> <!--(click)="addToCart(tempProduct)"-->
          </div>

          <br>

        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- begin footer -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<!--          <div class="form-inline float-left mr-1">-->
<!--            <select class="form-control" [value]="carsPerPage" (change)="changePageSize($event)">-->
<!--              <option value="4">4</option>-->
<!--              <option value="8">8</option>-->
<!--              <option value="12">12</option>-->
<!--              <option value="16">16</option>-->
<!--              <option value="20">20</option>-->
<!--            </select>-->
<!--          </div>-->

          <div class="btn-group flot-right">
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary active" *ngFor="let page of pageNumbers">1</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">2</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">3</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">4</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end footer -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

how to make pagination?

try

```
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<!--          <div class="form-inline float-left mr-1">-->
<!--            <select class="form-control" [value]="carsPerPage" (change)="changePageSize($event)">-->
<!--              <option value="4">4</option>-->
<!--              <option value="8">8</option>-->
<!--              <option value="12">12</option>-->
<!--              <option value="16">16</option>-->
<!--              <option value="20">20</option>-->
<!--            </select>-->
<!--          </div>-->

          <div class="btn-group flot-right">
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary active" *ngFor="let page of pageNumbers">1</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">2</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">3</button>-->
<!--            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">4</button>-->
          </div>
```

I tried to make a method that would help me implement pagination, but I can't get the length from cars$.wanted to take this function: return Array(Math.ceil(Number(this.cars$.subscribe(result => result.length)) / this.carsPerPage)), but an error occurred.

Comment: Could you show us the properties of `CarIniterface` and also include your error?

Comment: export interface CarInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  image: File | null
  price: number;
  count: number;
  model_id: number;
  order_id: number;
}

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71866922/1858357) shows and example of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code :

```
  <ul>
<li *ngFor="let car of cars$ | async">
  {{car.name}} {{car.model}}
</li>
<div *ngIf="cars$ | async as cars"> There are this many cars: {{cars.length}}
</div>
```

For more information check this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642580/length-property-does-not-exist-with-observables][1]

Comment: in general not subscribe twice to the same observable. You should use the ngIf to store a variable, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable):`<div *ngIf="cars$|async as cars"><div *ngFor="let car of cars">...</div>There are this many cars:{{cars.length}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use rxjs operator tap to get the length of the array and store in a variable. the "tap" operator execute the function inside when "someone" subscribe to the observable.

```
countCars=0;
pages:any[]=[]
this.cars$ = this.carService.getAllCars().pipe(
  tap((res:any[])=>{
       this.countCars=res.length; //if you want the length
       //we can create an array -only I'm interesting in the length-
       this.pages=new Array(Math.ceil(res.length/3))
  }));
```

Some like

```
<div
  *ngFor="
    let cars of cars$
      | async
      | slice: page * pageSize:page * pageSize + pageSize
  "
>
  {{ cars.id }} - {{ cars.text }}
</div>
<button (click)="page = page - 1">prev</button>
<button *ngFor="let pag of pages; let i = index" (click)="page = i">
  {{ i + 1 }}
</button>
<button (click)="page = page + 1">next</button>
```

makes the "pagination"

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jwzr5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.htmll)